# Add a tab before a visual selection

Tags: vimrc

I commonly find myself inserting a tab before some text. This is easy in insert mode, I'll just type a tab, but I would also like to be able to do it in visual mode. The issue is, if I press `>` in visual mode, it will indent the whole line. Instead I only want to insert a `tab` at the start of the visual selection and then re-select that text. Here is what I have so far:

```
vnoremap <leader>] <Esc>`<i<tab><Esc>gv
```

What this tries to do is:

- `<Esc>`   Escape the visual selection
- `` `< ``   Go to the start of the previous visual selection and enter insert mode
- `<tab>`  Add a tab
- `<Esc>` Escape insert mode
- `gv` And again go into visual mode and reselect the visual selection

The issue is, it seems that `gv` is no longer valid after entering in the `tab`. So what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You'd have to extend the selection to on the right by your `:h tabstop` setting, I suppose... but would not work if changing to another buffer. But it depends on what you exactly want: keep the exact same selection size? Select the new tab? Please explain more precisely what behaviour you'd expect and what's happening instead.

Comment: @Biggybi to select the previous selection -- that is, if I didn't add in the `tab`, whatever text was there before. For example, if `This is <v>the text<v>` and I add a tab at the start of the visual selection, it would look like this: `This is     <v>the text<v>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to select as many characters as were selected before (assuming it's `set selection=inclusive`) is `1v`. So it becomes:

```
xnoremap <leader>] c<tab><c-c>p`[1v
```

`c` --- delete selection into `@-` and start insert mode

`<tab>` --- insert literal tab

`<c-c>` --- stop insert mode and get back to normal

`p` --- put old selected text back

`'[` --- move cursor back to the start of "put"

`1v` --- reselect the same number of characters

Comment: wow that is so cool and creative, thank you! A couple questions: is `<c-c>` and `<esc>` in this case identical, or why do you use `<c-c>` ? Could you please explain he `1v` a bit more? I was testing it out a bit in vim but couldn't really understand what it does  or where to find it in help? For me it was always selecting 6 characters, regardless of what I selected last in visual mode.

Comment: @David542 (1) No real difference here; (2) Simply read `:h v`

Comment: @David542 personally i would have used escape

Comment: Thanks Matt for this useful tip. I often need to do the same operation on a block of lines. For example to insert a name or label at the start of each line. but I still don't know how to do it efficiently.

Comment: @elmclose `:h blockwise-operators`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Matt. I never knew this.